# Evaluate a function only on a subset of rows in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Is there a way to `mutate` on a subset of rows using a function that fails for non-included rows?

I am trying to use `my_func` but it fails for certain values (`5` in the toy example below). Can I evaluate this function on some rows but not others, returning `NA` for the other rows? I tried using `if_else` but it evaluates the function for all values, causing it to fail:

```
my_func = function(x) {
  if (any(x == 5)) stop("Fail!")
  return(x + 1)
}

data.frame(value = c(1, 5, 2)) %>%
  mutate(result = if_else(value == 5, NA, my_func(value)))
```

I could build a wrapper around `my_func` that removes breaking values, and insert those values into the return of `my_func` before returning, but that seems overly complicated.

UPDATE: The solution must not change `my_func`! I most recently encountered this problem where `my_func` is `quantreg::predict.rqss`.

Comment: For the NA values you could explicitly check for NA. `if_else(is.na(value) || value == 5, NA, my_func(value))`. What are some examples of other values it fails on?

Comment: @rpolicastro Try running what you suggest. It still evaluates `my_func` for all values, thereby failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution:

```r
eval_subset = function(x, fun, subset, false = NA) {
  x[subset] = fun(x[subset])  # Apply fun to values where subset == TRUE
  x[!subset] = false  # Insert default values else
  return(x)
}
```

Use it like this:

```r
data.frame(value = c(1, 5, 2)) %>%
  mutate(result = eval_subset(value, my_func, value != 5))
```

It's a bit cumbersome for my taste. Was hoping for something more built-in, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifelse` in `my_func` so that it can work on vector values.

```
my_func = function(x) {
  ifelse(is.na(x), NA, x + 5)
}
```

Now you can use it as :

```
data.frame(value = c(NA, 1, 2)) %>%
  mutate(result = my_func(value))
```

Also this returns the same output so you don't really need to check for `NA`s here.

```
data.frame(value = c(NA, 1, 2)) %>% mutate(result = value + 5)
```

---

If we can't really change `my_func` test for condition and `NA` explicitly :

```
my_func = function(x) {
  if (is.na(x) || x == 5) return(NA)
    else return(x + 1)
}
```

and apply the function rowwise :

```
data.frame(value = c(NA, 1, 2)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = my_func(value))
```

Comment: I updated the question to emphasize that I cannot change `my_func`. So your solution is not applicable, unfortunately. I also updated it to fail for the value `5` so that one is not tempted by R's inherent handling of `NA` in many cases.

Comment: You also changed `my_func` in your update. Again, I cannot do that. But I guess you could do the same thing using a wrapper function. I have posted an answer which does this vectorized so it's much faster/simpler to use than `rowwise`. I was looking for something more native to `dplyr` or other packages as this seems like a not-too-rare use case.